# How to prefix "admin" to routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, user-controls, laravel-6

I have recently installed laravel 6 for a project.

unfortunately, the routes don't work properly.

for example i lead a user to a page with this route..

```
{{ route('user.edit', ['id' => $user->id]) }}.
```

It should go to `admin/user/{user}/edit`.

But it goes to an unknown route like this:

```
/admin/admin/user//edit?id=1
```

my route :

```php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'IsVerified'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    route::resource('/user', 'UserController');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: try the command `php artisan route:list` you will get more details on how your routes look like. most likely that the place holder name is `userId` or `user_id`

Answer (score 3):

Your route model binding is incorrect, change your href to this

```
{{ route('user.edit', ['user' => $user]) }}
```

Result:

```
/admin/user/1/edit
```

Calling `Route::resource` on a model returns this url for an edit route

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                        | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                      |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/user/{user}/edit     | user.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController@edit                         | web,auth,IsVerified                             |
```

Note that the `user` model is used for the binding and then the ID is automatically fetched by the `getRouteKeyName` function which returns `id` by default

Answer (score 1):

1. The default placeholder for a resource is the model 'user' not 'id'

`{{ route('user.edit', ['id' => $user->id]) }}`

would become:

`{{ route('user.edit', $user) }}`

2. The double slash in your route is caused by the unecessary slash in

`route::resource('/user', 'UserController');`

which could just be:

`route::resource('user', 'UserController');`

3. As for the double 'admin', perhaps that is being output in your view, as your namespace and grouping appears correct.