# resource route doesnt work properly in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, routes, resources, laravel-6

i have recently installed laravel 6 for one of my project..and unfortunately resource route doesnt work properly.

i want to lead user to this route: admin/user/{user}/edit

but it go to   /admin/admin/user//edit?id=userid   or   /admin/admin/user/1/edit

my resource routes:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','IsVerified'],'prefix'=>'admin'],function(){

    route::resource('/user','UserController');

});
```

my `href="{{route('user.edit',['id'=>$user->id])}}"`

even i test -> `href="{{route('user.edit',$user->id)}}"`.

i hadn't got this problem in laravel 5.6/7/8

Comment: You already asked this question and we already answered

Comment: Question already asked by OP here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58136586/5581565

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prefix "admin" to routes in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136586/how-to-prefix-admin-to-routes-in-laravel)

Comment: You asked the question twice!

Answer (score 0):

Check `php artisan r:l`. You'll see the route expects a `{user}` parameter, not `{id}`.

```php
# Assume $user->id = 1
route('user.edit', ['user' => $user->id]) // yields: user/1/edit
route('user.edit', ['id' => $user->id])   // yields: user//edit?id=1
```

As for the grouping, try:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'IsVerified'])->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your href to this

```
{{ route('user.edit', ['user' => $user]) }}
```

Comment: One line solutions are better as a comment -- Unless you want to add details to your answer as to why your one line of code fixes the problem and explains what the problem is with OP code.